# How to embed jwplayer into google web toolkit application?

Tags: java, gwt, flash, jwplayer

glad to ask my first question in Stack Overflow :)
At work I'm developing a google web toolkit application and I need to embed a jwplayer inside it.

Do you have any suggestion about how to achieve this? I found [gwt2swf](http://code.google.com/p/gwt2swf/) but so far I couldn't make it work.
I have written this:

```
SWFWidget jwplayer = new SWFWidget("player.swf");
panel.add(jwplayer);
```

however I don't get the player, rather a message claiming that I don't have a proper flash player installed:

> Here should be a swf movieclip. You probably don't have FlashPlayer installed or have a PlayerVersion lower than 7.0.14.

Where should the file *player.swf* be located?
I tried to place it in the *war* directory alongside the main html file or on a remote http server but I always get that message...

Any suggestions?
Thanks!!

Comment: And how did you reference the swf file? (i.e. where did you place it and what was the relevant "src"?)

Comment: Well, in my case I placed it into WebContent, more precisely into a sub directory called "flash". Then in my case the code looks like this: `SWFWidget jwplayer = new SWFWidget("flash/player.swf", 100, 100);`

Comment: Nice work Giordano. As a friendly reminder, can you please post an answer to the question yourself and then accept that answer so that we can close this question? Also, you need to accept answers to previous questions if they fix your problem.

Comment: thanks for pointing this out, I made the change :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I found the reason it was not working, I didn't set the size of the jwplayer. Something like this:

```
SWFWidget jwplayer = new SWFWidget("player.swf", 100, 100);
panel.add(jwplayer);
```

will work :)